# Logging messages from useLayoutEffect & useEffect to the same React component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Just for fun, I tried to implement logging messages from my useLayoutEffect & useEffect hooks in the TextArea in the same React component:

```
const UseLayoutEffectExample = () => {

    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        console.log("useLayoutEffect")
        setText(text => text + "useLayoutEffect\n")
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect")
        setText(text => text + "useEffect\n")
    });

    return (
        <>
            <textarea
                readOnly={true}
                value={text}
                cols={15}
                rows={10}
                style={{resize: "none"}}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

As a result, I created an infinite loop with a couple of messages in the console like "Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate".
The reason of that behaviour is obvious. But suppose, I want to somehow print messages from "lifecycle functions" **for each render** to the **textarea**, not to the console, how should I implement this?

**NOTE:**
Of course I can avoid this problem by just creating an external variable, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: "But suppose, I want to somehow print messages from "lifecycle functions" to the same control, how should I implement that?" Isn't this also obvious from the reason for the render looping?

Comment: Just because you don't know how to do it doesn't mean it can't be done at all.

Comment: Are you asking how to log the state when it updates? I thought it would be obvious. Add the state you want to log as an `useEffect` hook dependency and remove the unconditional state update so you don't create a render loop. If this isn't what you are trying to do then please clarify the issue for us.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean add [text] to effects at the end and remove setText(...) inside effects body? But this way I'll be logging to console, but I need to log into the textarea. I want to remove console.log statements entirely!

Comment: What does "log into the textarea" even mean? Are you only wanting to update the `text` state so it can be rendered as the `textarea`'s value? Ok, use the `useEffect` hook to do that and don't unconditionally update the state by using an empty dependency array so the effect runs only once. Or why not just set the initial `text` state value to what you want to render and skip completely the `useEffect`?

Comment: It's work for empty DependencyList, but I want to do it for each render. The question seems far-fetched, but really I just want to know if I can use effects this way, or methods like setText(...) designed to be called from a component event handler (not from other hooks inside the same component), so that there is no loop.

Comment: The question doesn't seem far-fetched, it is more that there's a missing fundamental understanding of React state and lifecycle. It's unclear what you are trying to do. You can update state from the `useEffect` hook, just don't do it unconditionally as the warning tries to explain, this causes render looping.

Comment: 1) Remove setText from above code; 2) Watch for messages in the console; 3) Implement the same behavior (message appearing after each render), but the console messages appeared in the textarea; I don't know how to better explain the required behavior. I can definitely do this with a global variable, but I want to avoid it.

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand now. You are wanting console logs to be added to the `text` state so they are rendered into the text area, yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly ...

Comment: Something like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/logging-messages-from-uselayouteffect-useeffect-to-the-same-react-component-hqd5p?file=/src/App.js) demo?

Comment: You are monkey pathing window.console.log and thus breaking the loop. Interesting solution, but It seems to be a hack of React component subsystem). But this approach works. You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: True. An alternative is to create your own localized logging function that updates the  `text` state... but then this is basically just a normal function to update the state and console.log it as a side-effect at this point.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a second argument to `useEffect`  so it doesn't just call itself every time a re-render happens after calling 'setText()' Like

```js
const UseLayoutEffectExample = () => {

    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        console.log("useLayoutEffect")
        setText(text => text + "useLayoutEffect\n")
    },[text]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect")
        setText(text => text + "useEffect\n")
    },[text]);

    return (
        <>
            <textarea
                readOnly={true}
                value={text}
                cols={15}
                rows={10}
                style={{resize: "none"}}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

this way useEffect and useLayoutEffect only get called when `text` has changed.

Comment: This won't help, because: 1) The body of the useEffect method is executed at least once, regardless of the DependencyList state; 2) As soon as the first setState is executed, the Text variable is changed and marked as changed that leed to the furter recursion, and then everything goes in a circle. You will get the same behavior even if you comment out one of the effects. Just try.